# How to see changes in .jsp files without restarting server?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, catalina

I see it in this thread: [Why are my JSP changes are not reflected without restarting Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004676/why-my-jsp-changes-are-not-reflected-without-restarting-tomcat)
-do I have to specify development property to true if the true is by default?? But i still setted it, then removed the two mentioned files, restarted my IDE, but it's still not working, so what exactly should I do?
THIS QUESTION ALREADY HAS ANSWER HERE? I told i tried to do it but it's not working, check comments below...ah...

Comment: Did you tried to select 'automatically publish when resources change' tomcat publish settings?(in eclipse).

Comment: I'm using InteliJ idea, but i'll take a look for similiar option

Comment: Probably needless to say, but also ensure it is not a browser cache.

Comment: no it's not a browser cache for sure, i had an option "upload changed files automatically to server" setted to "never", now i changed it to always, but i have to set the default server somehow (intelij idea)

Comment: Is there a intelij user?? I configured default server like this: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-an-in-place-server-configuration.html#defaultServer but now i'm getting a message: default server 'server' does not need automatic upload, it already contains project, so I'm confused right now..

Answer (score -1):

Install Apache on your PC. Put the JSP file in the /htdocs/JSP folder in the Apache installation. You will have to create the JSP folder. Name the JSP file index.jsp. Open Apache and start the web service (the top one. Click Start) To view it, go to your browser and type in the following URL: 127.0.0.1/JSP. If that doesn't work, type in 127.0.0.1/JSP/index.jsp

This should help.

Comment: I know there is an easier solution, i find it already in my IDE, but i didn't finish it yet, check comments above