# Why do I need to restart the server after deploying hook?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Whenever I make a hook in `liferay 6.2`, then I need to restart the server to make the changes visible. I know that hooks are hot deployable. So, why the changes are not getting reflected without restart after deployment. Why do I need to restart the server? What to do in order to get rid of it?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to do with your hook and what doesn't work as expected before the restart? Also, is `liferay-7` tag a mistake?

Comment: Sorry liferay-7 tag is a mistake!!! I just wrote "changed"  to the /thml/portlet/journal_content/configuration.jsp hook and the word "changed" becomes visible to me after restart ..

Comment: You need to include the description of your hook into your question. You also need to specify the application server

Comment: Server is tomcat and i have already described the hook as you said..i don't think it matters where I describe it..

Comment: Restart isn't required in case of the hook, can you please try cleaning temp/work directory in your tomcat?

Comment: If you see your changes after restart it means the hook is deployed and processed properly. The question is why Tomcat does not pick the changes without restart? There could be many reasons for that. See if some of those described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004676/why-are-my-jsp-changes-are-not-reflected-without-restarting-tomcat apply to your configuration

Comment: Do you get the message for 1 hook available for use post deployment?