# Welcome page of the tomcat does not change

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml

My welcome page in `web.xml` file is `index.jsp`, when I updated the `index.jsp` file by my content manager servlet, the changes to `index.jsp` did not appear in welcome page and I still had the old contents. how can I fix this problem and update my welcome page file?

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Why are my JSP changes are not reflected without restarting Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2004676/2800058)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my JSP changes are not reflected without restarting Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004676/why-are-my-jsp-changes-are-not-reflected-without-restarting-tomcat)

Comment: Add code fencing for file names, capitalize appropriate pronouns, correct tenses.

Comment: can every body help me?